# cloudfront with elastic loadbalancer origin returns 403

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I have a web server behind a load balancer which is behind a cloudfront distribution. The idea for the cloudfront distribution with load balancer as origin was to restrict requests to the load balancer to only come from a front end web app. I followed this tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/restrict-access-to-load-balancer.html ensuring that

1. the elb origin cloudfront distribution puts in an origin header with a secret key value pair and
2. the load balancer has a rule to check for the http header with the correct key and value.

Hitting the loadbalancer directly with its DNS gives the expected 403 as desired. However, with postman when I make requests to the Cloudfront dns I get a 403.

Cloudfront ELB Origin Configuration:

[image]

Load Balancer Rule:

[image]

Error Message from Postman:

[image]

UPDATE:

I've added an error response action so that it redirects to the 'root' of my api. After doing this, requests with Postman no longer returns the 403 error from Cloudfront but returns the fixed 403 response message configured in the loadbalancer listener rule. It seems this way the request at least makes it through to the load balancer. Does this mean that the origin header is not being passed by Cloudfront? Also when I make a GET request to one of my endpoints pointing to the Cloudfront DNS with curl in the terminal it returns a good response, while the same request fails with Postman. Any other endpoint fails whether with curl or Postman with the 403 message of the listener rule.

[image]

Comment: What header name and value are you using? Feel free to post it after you change it to something that's not confidential.

Comment: x-cloudfrontHeader, cloudfrontValue123

Comment: Are you using the default dns name of the ELB as the CF origin?

Comment: What's the security group associated with the ELB?

Comment: my ELB security group accepts global ingress http requests and egress is TCP connection out to port 8080 on which my server is listening with my ec2 security group as destination. And yes, the ELB DNS is origin for CF.

Comment: Try setting the `origin protocol policy` to `http only`.

Comment: It still returns a 403. I plan on making https available in the future too anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the issue that you are having. Here is my working ELB and CF config:

[image: CF]

[image: ELB]

Comment: Thanks. Did you find you have to do anything additional with error response redirection or was that all?

Comment: That's all I did

Comment: The 403 error is not coming from the ALB rule. I have another CF distribution for a single-page website frontend which also gets a 403 error if you try to reach it with the frontend CF DNS. However in that case, I can redirect to index.html with the error response option. Here redirecting to a single endpoint of the API won't work.

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone else is banging their head against this as i did today.  i could successfully cUrl to my api server from the cmd line (cloudfront -> application lb -> api server) but our react client failed every time with HTTP 403.  turns out that i had not configured the particular host/domain at our server as an 'allowed origin' for CORS.